# Scenekit get SCNNode (box geometry) side to face in direction of vector

Tags: ios, swift, math, scenekit

I'm trying to get 4 box geometries to each face in one of these 4 directions:

`x: 1, y: 1, z: 1
x: -1, y: -1, z: 1
x: 1, y: -1, z: 1
x: -1, y: 1, z: 1`

The camera is located at x: 0, y: 0, z: 15. So as you can tell, the 4 vectors point towards the camera and to the up-right/down-right/up-left/down-left. I want each one of my boxes to have a side in the direction of one of these vectors, and to then move them in that direction.

When I calculate the rotation in radians of these vectors and apply them as euler angles, the box rotates around its own axes so I don't get the effect I desire.

I tried to change the pivot before applying the euler angles, but I can't make much sense of it.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Speaking of "left" and "right" in 3D space is confusing if you don't have a reference direction. And why does the camera matter if you're rotating the *boxes*? A rotation matrix can be directly computed from these vectors without using Euler angles and the like.

Comment: How do I compute a rotation matrix from these angles?